# Нужно ли обособлять "тем самым"?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Гоголь не даёт чёткого описания внешности главного героя, тем самым, даёт пофантазировать на эту тему.

Answer (score 4):

**Гоголь не даёт чёткого описания внешности главного героя, тем самым даёт пофантазировать на эту тему.**

[http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%2C+тем+самым](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%2C+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC)

Вопрос № 259902
т**ем самым - выделяется ли запятыми**
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Нет, слова ***тем самым*** вводными не являются и не обособляются. В очень редких случаях, когда тем самым выступает в функции союза, перед ним ставится запятая: Нагрубил женщине, тем самым поставил себя в неловкое положение.

Примечание: повтор глагола ***дает***.

Возможное редактирование: **Гоголь не приводит чёткого описания внешности главного героя и тем самым даёт возможность пофантазировать на эту тему**

Comment: Именно "даёт **возможность** пофантазировать". Без слова "возможность" фразу нельзя считать грамотно построенной.